# Are there books in the other Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars, continuity, the-last-jedi

One part of the trailer for *The Last Jedi* always puzzled me: We see one shot of what looks like a shelf of books - you know; with covers, spines, paper pages, etc.

[image: shelf of books?]

Later we get this close up and see what appear to be paper pages in the book(s):

[image: pages of book?]

The problem is I don't remember seeing books in Star Wars before, so I'm wondering, **have there been any books in the Star Wars movies* before this?** I always figured Star Wars would only have digital "soft copies" for reading via console or holograms etc. like the digital information available in the Jedi archives.

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>Preferred sources: Movies > old version of "canon" >
 new Disney "canon"</sub>

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Stationery

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Book

Comment: @Valorum yes, there is a wiki page on books, but most of the things listed appear to be disney additions (rebels, new books, etc.) which is why this all feels like Disney not doing their homework. I have since clarified that I am asking about the movies first and old canon second and everything else third.

Comment: How is that 'not doing their homework'?  The movies are a small portion of time in a small portion of a galaxy.  Just because you don't see any doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: Given that the movies show planets where some people are eking out a very basic existence, still using animals for transport etc. and some species still live in tents and caves, it should not be surprising that books still persist as a method of storing information. Just as in our world there are people and cultures who live a lifestyle that pre-dates the industrial age, let alone the digital age.

Comment: Presumably those books are *very, very* old, before holochrons and electronic information storage became available.

Comment: @RedCaio please stop attributing New Canon to Disney. They had no say in what's canon and what's not. All those canon/non-canon decisions lie with the **Lucasfilm Story Group** alone.

Comment: @pepoluan I am certainly not the only one on SFF SE that referres to it that way. I suspect the fact that Disney owns Lucasfilm just may have lead to Disney having some part in determining what is and is not canon. But you can ask Valorum if you want. :D Have a great day.

Answer (score 10):

Just recently in the new novel **Star Wars: Battlefront II - Inferno Squad**, it is mentioned that a Moff has a book collection, but they are all very old and the characters mentioned that they had never seen a physical book before:

> "Don't miss a chance to look into the library - the moff has a
>   collection of actual old *books*. Don't see that every day."

In response to this, a character says:

> "I've never seen a book collection..."

So it can be assumed that books exist, but they are very old and rarely seen in physical form in the movie eras.