# Is the 'Book of Boba Fett' a diegetic entity?

Tags: star-wars

Walking past a poster just now made me realize what always seemed strange to me about the film title *The Book of Boba Fett* (which I haven't watched, but the Wikipedia entry makes no mention of a book in the plot). As far as I remember, no mention of or other references to books are made in at least the first two Star Wars trilogies.

So now I wonder if this *Book of Boba Fett* is an existing book or other entity in the Star Wars universe. Does this book actually exist in the Star Wars universe?

Comment: We did see some of the "Jedi sacred texts" that looked like bound books in *Last Skywalker*.

Comment: Your final sentence is asking an entirely different question (one that has [already been asked elsewhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165780/are-there-books-in-the-other-star-wars-movies)) so I've edited it to match the rest of the wording.

Comment: I think the only answer that can be given is, "Not yet." Is there a "Book of Bobba Fett" mentioned in the (so far) two episodes of the show? No. Might one be added at some point in the narrative? Perhaps.

Comment: The “Star Wars,” those series of tales recounting _the Further Adventures of Luke Skywalker_ and its derivatives is from the Journal of the Whills. Whether the Whills shrewdly facilitated a licensed intellectual property line of Expanded Universe stories, canon or Legends works to be written by others, or such adventures like those recounted in The Book of Boba Fett is pretty much still unanswered. But everything we see is based on the stories and characters from _The Journal._

Comment: Presumably, it's either a play on "books" of scripture or history, implying that Boba Fett writes history (as victors do), or to say that you're in Boba's "good book" (opposed to the "bad book", which is of course the show)

Comment: @PeterNielsen But that implies the title is an out-of-universe reference, based on customs or idioms from our universe.

Comment: @Joachim - The style of the show is being done in the manner of an epic, suggesting strongly that it is building the story up to something monumental. As such, the title of the show is an out-of-universe artefact. However, that being said, it is quite possible that this will eventually be mirrored in-universe with an actual "Book of Boba Fett."

Comment: @GeoffAtkins That would be an answer to my question: "*the title of the show is an out-of-universe artefact*". But is it? I get that this title is likely given to give the story the allure of an epic, or simply to reflect the structure of the film(s), but that's what I found strange about it: whereas former titles are symbolic/minimalistic representations of the plot (e.g. The Empire Strikes Back), this one *seems* to refer to how its audience is supposed to - or at least can - interpret the plot/structure. There is a reversal happening here, which I can't properly place, hence the question.

Comment: @Joachim - I would agree that it appears so. But it also is certainly plausible that the shows writers will include an in-universe book at some point, because that would fit with the narrative conventions which the show does appear to be following.

Comment: @SillybutTrue You describe Lucas' original plan for the journal that was ultimately dropped. Do we have enough canon information to say that its current incarnation (limited as it to a few mentions) is meant as that same diegetic source of truth?

Comment: My opinion is that book just means "story" in this context. The word is used with some artistic freedom. Something similar is used for example in *The Last Airbender* where each season is refered to as a book while to my knowledge it doesn't refer to actual books.

Comment: @IvoBeckers But it makes sense in a universe where books are used to register events of historical significance, like in that of Avatar. But that's what my question is about: does this titular book refer to such an object (or similar) in the Star Wars universe?

Answer (score 1):

No, 'The Book of Boba Fett doesn't refer to a book,

> the show is called The Book of Boba Fett because it is a show that explores the life of the titular character, who used to be a famous bounty hunter but has since left that life to pursue a new one as the head of a family in Jabba’s former territory. In a way, we see Jabba’s life chapter per chapter in this “book.”

> Aside from the fact that every episode in The Book of Boba Fett is called a chapter instead of simply an episode, we can also say that this series is a book that tells us the story of Fett in a manner that has been consistent with the previous Star Wars films and the Marvel-published Star Wars comics. Of course, we can also say that this is a book that shows a new chapter in the famed bounty hunter’s life.

> That said, this is a show that is more of a book about Boba Fett’s experiences in life and how he finally decided to turn away from his old life as a bounty hunter to establish a family under his own leadership and protection. In a way, he is opening a new chapter in his book.

So no its not exactly a book but just a metaphor for Boba's life
[(source for the quoted paragraphs)](https://fictionhorizon.com/why-is-the-show-called-the-book-of-boba-fett/).